# Simple Postgres Procedure with 2 table updates does not work

Tags: postgresql

I'm programmer from MSSQL to PostgreSQL. I'm having difficulty in getting the simple procedure to work. I'm sure I'm missing something. Seeking your expertise.

In the below I'm creating a permanent tableA and temporary tableB. I'm trying to update by doing a join on tableA and B. For some reason

1. it expects all the table to be available. I have large column list so i went with select into.
2. I executed the statements individually and only when 2 tables are created it allows to created procedure
3. even after creating procedure successfully when i get run time error when i try to call the procedure

I tried cte but even then it errors somewhere in the Update statement. This is just a sample code i posted. Thanks for your time.

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE "ASG"."loadABC"()

LANGUAGE SQL

AS $$

drop table "tableA";

SELECT "Code", c1, c2, c3
INTO "tableA"
FROM 
(SELECT 1 "Code", 'A' c1, 'B' c2, 'update c' c3
union SELECT 2 "Code", 'A' c1, 'B' c2, 'update c' c3
union SELECT 3 "Code", 'A' c1, 'B' c2, 'update c' c3 
)A
--JOIN other tables not necessary for this now
;


SELECT "Code", c1, c2, c3
INTO TEMPORARY TABLE "tableB"
FROM 
(SELECT 1 "Code", 'A' c1, 'B' c2, 'update c' c3
union SELECT 2 "Code", 'A' c1, 'B' c2, 'update c' c3
union SELECT 3 "Code", 'A' c1, 'B' c2, 'update c' c3 
)B;

update "tableA" A 
set "c3" = b."c2"
from "tableB" b
where 
(A."Code" = b."Code");

drop table "tableB";

$$;
```

Comment: I'm sorry not sure why the programing code is not as formatted. It gets posted like a paragraph however i format it during posting this question.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Why all those intermediate tables? Just run a single UPDATE using a FROM clause with the source tables (but remember to **not** repeat the target table in the FROM clause - this is different from SQL Server). There is no need to store intermediate results in Postgres. But you have obfuscated your actual code so much that it is impossible to tell what a more efficient approach should look like

Comment: `UNION ALL` to say the least ...

Comment: What is the runtime error you are getting?

Comment: The concept is build permanent table A, build temporary tableB, update table A with one of column from temporary table B.
Error while creation of proc 
PgADmin 4.8

Comment: The concept is build permanent table A, build temporary tableB, update table A with one of column from temporary table B. 
Error while creation of proc 
ERROR:  relation "tableB" does not exist
LINE 114: from tableB t
               ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 4140
PgADmin 4.8

Comment: Any template code you could suggest or post which i can modify and try would be helpful.
Proc creation with 1 perm tableA, the other temp tableB, update one column of tableA with one column from tableB.

I tried online but nothing of this combination. i 'm pretty decent in SQL but in postgre its challenging.